# How to fix error 102 on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**i have problems in sql please help me
sql query :**

```
SELECT CASE
 WHEN (GROUPING(Staff.FirstName + ' ' + Staff.LastName ) = 1) THEN 'ALL'
  ELSE ISNULL(Staff.FirstName + ' ' + Staff.LastName , 'UNKNOWN') END AS Staff.FirstName + ' ' + Staff.LastName  ,  Count( Patient.PatientUniqueID ) AS CountOfPatientID 
  FROM patient LEFT JOIN 
  ((bInsurance RIGHT JOIN 
  ((Admit LEFT JOIN Staff ON Admit.DoctorRef = Staff.GeneralID) LEFT JOIN bWard ON Admit.WardRef = bWard.WardID) 
  ON bInsurance.InsurID = Admit.InsuranceRef)
   LEFT JOIN (Staff AS Staff_Treat RIGHT JOIN PTreat ON Staff_Treat.GeneralID = PTreat.DoctorRef)
    ON Admit.AdmitID = PTreat.AdmitRef) ON patient.PatientUniqueID = Admit.PatientUniqueRef
   Where (PatientUniqueID IN(
    SELECT Patient.PatientUniqueID
     FROM Staff AS StaffUserInf RIGHT JOIN 
     ((((bWard RIGHT JOIN  (Staff RIGHT JOIN Admit ON Staff.StaffID=Admit.DoctorRef) ON  bWard.WardID=Admit.WardRef)
      LEFT JOIN Staff AS Staff_1 ON  Admit.AssistantRef=Staff_1.StaffID)
       RIGHT JOIN Patient ON  Admit.PatientUniqueRef=Patient.PatientUniqueID)
        LEFT JOIN PTreat ON  Admit.AdmitID=PTreat.AdmitRef)
         ON StaffUserInf.UserName=Admit.CreatedBy  Where  1 = 1 ) ) 
GROUP BY Staff.FirstName + ' ' + Staff.LastName   ;With Cube
```

**error :
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near ')'.**

Comment: Incorrect syntax is fixed by correcting the syntax. So start small with select from the first table and start correcting the syntax as you go along. You have issues with your aliases and your WITH CUBE to begin with

Comment: I reverted the most recent edit because, although it may have made the SQL more readable, it also meant that the line numbers in the error messages no longer corresponded with the code.